# can player join multiple rooms? PUN

Tags: animation, multiplayer, photon

In Photon multiplayer for unity,
can player join multiple room or sync player movement throughout multiple rooms in photon multiplayer game ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered on Photon's forum at [this link](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/14710/can-player-join-multiple-rooms).

PUN and Photon realtime clients, in general, can be joined to a single room at the same time.